# Saving fasta sequence in the right format using cat and paste functions

Tags: r, cat

I'm trying to retrieve a sequence of interest using the library BSgenome. I want to save the sequence in a fasta format like so:

```
>Ggallus_Gene_name
ACGTCCCCCCCCC.........
```

But I can't seem to get my data in this format in my data seq. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(BSgenome)
biocLite("BSgenome.Ggallus.UCSC.galGal4")
library(BSgenome.Ggallus.UCSC.galGal4)
seq=capture.output(cat(paste('>Ggallus_CRX',
    '\n',getSeq(Ggallus,"chr5",start=54293885,end=54318108))))
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulate your query as a GRanges (start, end, and names could be vectors, e.g., of 10,000 different genes)

```
query = GRanges("chr5", IRanges(54293885, 54318108, names="Ggallus_Gene_name"))
```

then retrieve the sequences

```
seqs = getSeq(Ggallus, query)
```

and write them out

```
writeXStringSet(seqs, "my_file.fasta")
```

leading to the first few lines

```
>Ggallus_Gene_name
GAGCGCGGCCCTCCCGCCCGGCCCCGGCCTCCCCCGCTCCGCCCGGCGCTGCGCGGCCCCGCTCCGCCTCCTCCCCCCGG
GGCGTGGGGCCGCGGCGGGGGCTCGGGCAGGTGGAGGTGACCTCCGTGCTGCCGCCCCTCCCGCCCGCCTTCCTGCCTTC
CTCCCTCCGCGGGAAGGAGGGGAGGGAAGTGGAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAGAGAAAAAAGGGAGAGAAGGAGAAAAAA
AAAAAGGGGAAAAAAAAAAAGCAGAGGGCCCCAAGGCATTTCTCAACCAAGGGCGCGATTGTGCAGCGCGGCCCCCCTCT
...
```

DNAStringSets fomr different sources can be concatenated and written out, `writeXStringSet(c(seqs1, seqs2), "my_file.fasta"))` or previous files can be appended to `writeXStringSet(seqs2, "my_file.fasta", append=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin!! this really helped. If I have multiple coordinates from the same species this will definitely help but how about if I have coordinates from different species like from human and  mouse and I want to extract them like above?